# Query Responds With Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Tags: php, mysql

Would someone please explain to me what is wrong with this??

```
SELECT COUNT (`ID`) FROM `tableImSpecifying` WHERE `VisitorsEmail` = '$VarThatHoldsEmailFromA$_POSTInput'
```

This is part of a program I am writing while following a tutorial but I'm hung up on how to fix this. I'd be most appreciative and I thank you in advance if anyone can tell me how to fix this.

Here's the error I'm seeing:

> FUNCTION myhost_classifieds.COUNT does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

What baffles me is I have similar queries above this one that work properly and I've checked the syntax over & over but I don't see what's wrong.

Comment: Probably has something to do with your attempt at ramming a bunch of variables together.  You shouldn't be using raw data in a query without escaping it anyway!  Use prepared/parameterized queries, or you will find yourself hacked via SQL injection very quickly.

Comment: I would guess your problem is here: `$VarThatHoldsEmailFromA$_POSTInput` Try echoing that to see if its correct

Comment: Hi @Brad Could you elaborate?? If Im ramming a bunch of variables together it's not with ill (black hat) intent. Not at all. I'm just a novice webmaster trying to learn all I can.

Comment: @StuartKaufman, as SSHThis said, `$VarThatHoldsEmailFromA$_POSTInput` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The solution might be as simple as removing the space between `COUNT` and `(ID)`. Can we see your complete PHP/mySQL code?

Comment: The space after COUNT looks wrong. Can you post the exact query you are making?

Comment: @SSHThis I ahve echoed this and it does display the proper email data.

Comment: Hi everyone, Some of you have requested complete source code. I would love to accomodate such requests but I'm unsure about the vulnerability I may expose myself to by posting such code

Comment: Sweeet!! I LOVE You Guys!! The Space fixed it. (Well... Removal of the space) Thanks So Much!!

Comment: @Brad BTW, I DO have the data sanitized before this query but thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @StuartKaufman complete source code may be too much, from query creation to sending it to the database would be good. As per your vulnerabilities inserting varialbes directly in the query without validation or sanitazion will lead to a SQL injection vulnerability. if present the currently posted code may be enought to exploit it. You say you have the sada sanitized, so it shouldn't be a problem. Please refer to: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_injection

Comment: what is *not* wrong with this?

Comment: Posting a code snippet that shows a vulnerability would not be likely to make you less secure than you already are.  There are bots roaming the internet, trying to drop your tables as we speak.  Unfortunately, these days someone does not have to be motivated to attack you.  Most trivial attacks are automatic.

Answer (score 29):

This:

> FUNCTION myhost_classifieds.COUNT does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Would prompt you [to read this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/function-resolution.html)

Which leads you to alter this:

```
COUNT (`ID`)
```

To:

```
COUNT(`ID`)
```

(note the removed space).

(you could also fiddle around with [`IGNORE_SPACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ignore_space), but I wouldn't recommend it for a novice.

Answer (score 13):

Change:

```
SELECT COUNT (`ID`)
```

to

```
SELECT COUNT(`ID`)
```

The space is messing it up.

Answer (score 7):

In simple terms, according to Wrikken, on the [SQL Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/function-resolution.html) it says,

> To use the name as a function call in an expression, there must be no whitespace between the name and the following ( parenthesis character.

So the expression,

```
SELECT COUNT (`ID`) FROM `tableImSpecifying` WHERE `VisitorsEmail` = '$VarThatHoldsEmailFromA$_POSTInput'
```

doesn't work because there is a whitespace between COUNT and  the ( ). Simply remove the whitespace and change it to:

```
SELECT COUNT('ID') ...
```

Comment: The whitespace was the issue for me too, unbelievable...thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 SELECT COUNT(`ID`) FROM `tableImSpecifying` WHERE `VisitorsEmail` = '$VarThatHoldsEmailFromA$_POSTInput'
            ^^-------remove space here
```

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same problem while running the query

```
SELECT MIN (released_year) FROM books
```

where i encountered the error

```
FUNCTION records.MIN does not exist.
Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual.
```

But it worked when i removed the space between MIN and (released_year) so the correct one is:

```
SELECT MIN(released_year) FROM books
```

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL doesn't like white space after function names. Try taking out the space after COUNT.

I also take it that those variable names are just an example and your not actually using them in production!