# Count all records from database where due date matches todays date

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I need to count all records from database where due date matches today date.
I found out that I should be able to do this using COUNT and CURDATE.
But I am not able to get it right:

```
SELECT COUNT (id) FROM tasks WHERE due_date = CURDATE
```

Comment: What are a few sample records from your table?

Comment: `CURDATE()` is a _function_, note the parentheses.  Fix that and your query will run.

Comment: Try SELECT COUNT(id), without the space. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16157356/query-responds-with-check-the-function-name-parsing-and-resolution-section-in

Comment: There are two errors. Remove the space after count, and add parentheses after curdate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried my self and this is working :

```
SELECT count(id) FROM `tasks ` WHERE due_date= CURRENT_DATE
```

**OR**

```
SELECT count(id) FROM `tasks ` WHERE due_date =  CURDATE()
```

[Read this it will clear you Concepts](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_curdate.asp)

Answer (score 2):

SELECT COUNT (id) FROM tasks WHERE due_date = CURDATE
Just remove space between COUNT and (id) will work properly.

Comment: CURDATE() is a function